# Copy a file from sdcard location to another location in c language in Android

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I have written a code to copy a text file from one location(`/mnt/sdcard/Appfolder/filename.txt`) to another(`/data/test/log.txt`) in Android device in C language and building it using `ndk`.

I donot know the name of the file so i have put *.txt as source file.

```
int copy_file(char* src, char *dest) {

  FILE *p,*q;
  char *file1,*file2;
  int ch;

  file1 = src;
  p=fopen(file1,"r");
  if(p==NULL){
      printf("cannot open %s",file1);
      exit(0);
  }

   file2 = dest;
  q=fopen(file2,"w");
  if(q==NULL){
      printf("cannot open %s",file2);
      exit(0);
  }
  while((ch=getc(p))!=EOF)
      putc(ch,q);
  printf("\nCOMPLETED");
  fclose(p);
  fclose(q);
 return 0;
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
cannot open /mnt/sdcard/Appfolder/<filename.txt>
```

What am I doing wrong?

The file attributes of the  is 660.

Comment: You have a bigger problem than the error you're getting, and that is that you haven't read the manual page for [`getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc), because it does *not* return a `char`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg updated,Btw I get the error before that.

Comment: As for your problem, you might want to use e.g. [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) to print the actuall error you get.

Comment: "The file attributes for the .. is 660" ?

Comment: @moffeltje for the .."root".Is that what you asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `system()` function to do this. For example, for Windows, you could just use the copy command to copy txt files.

```
system("copy C:\src\dir\*.txt C:\dest\dir\");
```

Or with variables (pseudo code):

```
#define PATH_MAX        4096


char command[MAX_PATH * 2 + 6];
char *file1 = src, *file2 = dest;


strcpy(command, "copy ");
strcat(command, file1);
strcat(command, " ");
strcat(command, file2);

system(command);
```

Comment: This works except that I have to change : "copy" to cp.But i couldnt remove the file using system("rm <filename>") , neither "remove" works.Any idea?

Comment: If you'd like to remove the "old" file, you could better move it (not sure which os you have) with the commands move or mv

Comment: I have android and I doing all these operation first on command line via adb.cp works and so does system("cp..") in the c code.Similiarly "rm" works on command line but not inside system("rm..").I think this is same as running the code on Linux, only difference is programmatically.

Comment: Did mv have any luck?

Comment: I didnt try move, I dont want to move rather I want to delete it completely?Where do you expect me to move it?

Comment: Instead of copying, you could just move the file to the destination so that you do not have to delete the 'old file', bc there isn't any.